# Fetch Cookies for Login Page URL, where its REST API is restricted

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest, selenium-webdriver

It is very slow to follow selenium, as it needs to load web drivers and locate HTML elements and enter data.

I have written a REST based framework, where all the REST API Calls are working fine.
but Login REST API is restricted by the organization, so as an alternative I have written a selenium logic where it opens login URL in a webpage, enters valid credentials.

I have used selenium driver object (created above) to fetch cookies and cookies were passed to other REST API calls.

So, is there any alternative other than selenium to fetch the cookies, where REST API access is denied?

Comment: for a speedier option use HTMLUnit as the webdriver/browser.  You could also receive cookies if they are sent via http response without using Selenium or a browser.  If they are set via javascript, then you need something that would understand that call.  Maybe node.js?

Comment: Just a note:  Using a browser is really the best way to test.  (if the clients/consumers will also be using a browser).  If you are only mocking http calls, then you won't have browser specific behavior from the test.  (CORS restrictions in particular would be something only a browser would have and re-writing all those restrictions along with reading CORS headers would be quite a pain...)